# Google analytics Active Users in UserID View

Tags: google-analytics

I created a UserID View for the GA Property and the active users in UserID View is very much less than the normal view..Is this expected?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as the name suggests the UserID view only contains data where you've set the UserID, thus less than in the normal view where everyone is counted.